# SQL, вопрос о паре индексов

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Возможно ли каким-то образом записать индексы парой, например `cityID` и `mode`, сделав оба уникальными? Т.е. не по отдельности, а так, чтобы предотвратить записи вида

```
+---------------------------------+
| cityID | url          | mode    |
+---------------------------------+
|707     |"_неважно_"   |current  |
+---------------------------------+
|707     |"_неважно_2_" |current  |
+---------------------------------+
```

Спрашиваю именно о паре, потому что если они будут уникальными по отдельности, то не получется сделать такое:

```
+---------------------------------+
| cityID | url          | mode    |
+---------------------------------+
|707     |"_неважно_"   |current  |
+---------------------------------+
|7089    |"_неважно_2_" |current  |
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Table_cityID_mode_uindex ON db.Table (cityID, mode);
```